# jQuery UI Autocomplete - Also search in title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this code for add autocomplete to an input. Is working fine, but the user should be able of search also in the titles (a.k.a "*area*").

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    //Autocomplete
    $(function() {
        $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
            _create: function() {
                this._super();
                this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-area)");
            },

            _renderMenu: function(ul,items) {
                var that = this,
                    currentarea = "";

                $.each( items, function(index,item) {
                    var li;
                    if (item.area !== currentarea) {
                        ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-area' aria-label='"+item.area+"'>" + item.area + "</li>");
                        currentarea = item.area;
                    }

                    li = that._renderItemData(ul,item);

                    if (item.area) {
                        li.attr("aria-label", item.area + ":" + item.label);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        var data = [
            //Title : Value
            { area: "Something", label: "ST A" },
            { area: "Something", label: "ST B" },
            { area: "Other thing", label: "OT A" },
            { area: "Other thing", label: "OT B" },
            { area: "This thing", label: "TT A" }
        ];

        $( "#the_things" ).catcomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: data
        });
    });
});
```

So, if the user writes "Something" should appear the title and the related value. Now is only searching in the values ("*label*").

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): https://jsfiddle.net/p91w9y1o/

What I need to do for make it search in both places?

Comment: Do you want to have it only search `area` or both? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @twisty, I need to search in both. What I've tried is in the MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. One way is to provide a function to your Source instead of data.

> **Function**: The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:
>
> - A `request` object, with a single `term` property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters `"new yo"` in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal `"new yo"`.
> - A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the `response` callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.
>
> When filtering data locally, you can make use of the built-in `$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex` function. It'll take a single string argument and escape all regex characters, making the result safe to pass to `new RegExp()`.

See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

This might look like this:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-area)");
    },

    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentarea = "";

      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li;
        if (item.area !== currentarea) {
          ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-area' aria-label='" + item.area + "'>" + item.area + "</li>");
          currentarea = item.area;
        }

        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);

        if (item.area) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.area + ":" + item.label);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  var data = [{
    area: "Something",
    label: "ST A"
  }, {
    area: "Something",
    label: "ST B"
  }, {
    area: "Other thing",
    label: "OT A"
  }, {
    area: "Other thing",
    label: "OT B"
  }, {
    area: "This thing",
    label: "TT A"
  }];

  $("#the_things").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var results = [];
      $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        if (v.area.toLowerCase().search(req.term) !== -1) {
          results.push(v);
        }
        resp(results);
      })
    }
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ofnt86r9/

**Update**

New Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ofnt86r9/2/

```
  $("#the_things").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var results = [];
      $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        if ((v.area.toLowerCase().search(req.term.toLowerCase()) !== -1) || (v.label.toLowerCase().search(req.term.toLowerCase()) !== -1)) {
          results.push(v);
        }
        resp(results);
      })
    }
  });
```

This will check both `area` and `label` of the `term`.

Comment: Now is just searching in the area, right? I need both. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Yes, updated my answer. An `OR` statement can allow for both.